# How can I transfer a dumped database in Postgres CLI from my remote server to my remote server or my local machine?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Normally, when I transfer a dumped database from postgres CLI in my local machine, I can simply `sftp my_user_name@my_ip` remotely from postgres CLI to my local machine without any problems. However, when it comes to my remote server, this seems like I have already connected with my server via ssh connection; thus, when I `sudo su - postgres` to open up postgres CLI, I cannot use the same technique to

i)`sftp my_user_name@my_ip`. It said request `Connection timed out`; I think this may be because they are not in the same WiFI network connection.

ii) or even `sftp ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.....amazonaws.com`. It said `my aws ec2 server: Permission denied (public key)`

I think this may result from I have made a SSH connection already, so if i sftp again, this will duplicate with the previous SSH connection.

Any idea ?? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be simple. I will help you here. Firstly are both machines on same network ? your first comment looks like they are not on same network or we can say they are not connected to each other hence connection timed out.  on your second comment; u would need to use pem file to connect to ec2.. Please give all details ; and I will give you commands etc. needed.  Also, check security group of destination server if port 22 is open.

Comment: Thank you so much :) Actually for i), it is on the same network, but it has a timed out connection somehow. For ii), i have added my key pair to aws ec2 key pair. Let say "macbook-desktop" name consisting of my public key contents here. However, do i need to create my pem file again, sir? It seems like I do not have any pem file except Key Pair name.

Comment: It seems like my ec2 suggests that my .pem file is "pep-macbook.pem", I created my key pair by copying "id_rsa.pub" in my mac directory (~.ssh/id_rsa.pub) and assign name to be "pep-macbook" in Key Pairs panel in AWS. However, doing this way I think I only have "id_rsa.pub" pem file in my mac directory. And, port 22 is opened btw.

Comment: Please bear with me. I am only a developer, so I don't know server things much  : (

Comment: when u create ec2 instance; aws gives u a pem file which u can download on ur laptop. put it in any directory and then do ssh to ur ec2 by using -i option.  .. dont get confused by id_rsa etc.. thats different use case.